# убирать focus-within при клике(:active)

Tags: css

как можно убрать focus-within с элемента списка по клику на ссылку.
При фокусе должен меняться фон а при ховере и клике фона быть не должно. Или делать фокус на ссылку, но тогда не захватывает фон где абсолютная стрелка в :after.

вот [codepen](https://codepen.io/root3x/pen/MWEKLdv)

```
$primary: #9D5CD0
$light-primary: #C283F3
$dark-primary: #7943A4
$white: #fff

a
  text-decoration: none
ul, li
  list-style: none
  
.bottomnav
  background-color: #333
  &__list
    display: flex
  &__item
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 5px
    &:not(:last-child)
      margin-right: 93px
    &:focus-within
      outline: none
      background-color: $primary
  &__link
    position: relative
    display: inline-block
    max-width: 200px
    font-size: 18px
    line-height: 24.5px
    color: $white
    word-wrap: break-word
    transition: color .3s
    &::after
      content: ''
      position: absolute
      top: 8px
      right: -14px
      display: inline-block
      width: 8px
      height: 8px
      border-left: 1px solid $white
      border-bottom: 1px solid $white
      transform: rotate(-45deg)
      transition: border-color .3s
    &:focus-visible
      outline: none
      // background-color: $primary
    &:hover
      color: $light-primary
      &::after
        border-color: $light-primary
    &:active
      color: $dark-primary
      &::after
        border-color: $dark-primary
```

```
<nav class="bottomnav">
  <ul class="bottomnav__list d-flex">
    <li class="bottomnav__item">
      <a href="#" class="bottomnav__link">
        Реализм
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bottomnav__item">
      <a href="#" class="bottomnav__link">
        Импрессионизм
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bottomnav__item">
      <a href="#" class="bottomnav__link">
        Постимпрессионизм
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bottomnav__item">
      <a href="#" class="bottomnav__link">
        Авангард
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bottomnav__item">
      <a href="#" class="bottomnav__link">
        Футуризм
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: "При фокусе должен меняться фон а при ховере и клике фона быть не должно." Противоречий не находите? :focus активируется при клике мышью.

Comment: да но focus-visible не оставляет активный фокус